# reading preferences as int throws exception

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to read the value stored in preferences as Int, its throwing me classcast exception. Here is the code

```
SharedPreferences prefs = ct.getSharedPreferences("volumepreference", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        int Past_phone_audio_mode = -1;

        try
        {
            Past_phone_audio_mode = prefs.getInt("volumestate", -1);
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {

        }
```

May i know whats wrong in my code

Comment: Show code where saving value in `SharedPreferences`

Comment: make sure `volumestate` you have saved in sharedpref is `int` type

Comment: No, actually the code above executes for the first time

Answer (score 2):

To save a preference int value:

```
    final SharedPreferences prefs =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    // Get preference in editor mode
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    // Set the Integer value
    editor.putInt("volumestate", 1);

    // Finally, save changes
    editor.apply();
```

Comment: Hi, why should i save for the first time, if the value does not exist for the preference, then it should return me -1 correct?

Comment: Yes, it should. However I prefer to save a default value the first time. Maybe I experimented some idiosyncrasies in the past. Now I always save a default value first.